# Cannot use Apple services after installing MacOS in Windows with Virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I wanted to delve a bit into developing apps in Swift and wanted to try to install MacOS in my Windows laptop. I got the image and managed to install it but the problem I am facing is that I cannot use iMessage, and other services, for instance. Am I missing any additional step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That's the way it's supposed to work

Per the [EULA](https://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/macOSSonoma.pdf), you can only virtualize macOS on Apple hardware. I'd also question whatever "image" you have, macOS isn't distributed that way.

> (iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software, or
> any prior macOS or OS X operating system software or subsequent release of the Apple
> Software, within virtual operating system environments on each Apple-branded computer you
> own or control that is already running the Apple Software, for purposes of: (a) software
> development; (b) testing during software development; (c) using macOS Server; or (d) personal,
> non-commercial use.

Comment: Oh, didn't knew that! Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @YiQiangJi If you just want to do Swift, you can install and use Swift on other than macOS.

Comment: do you have any documentation that I can look at? Thanks!